# CRM 2011 - Multiple Forms against one Entity

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

**Entity**:

Degree

**Forms**:

1. Graduation
2. Post Graduation

**Requirement**:

When user clicks on New, the Graduation form opens up. Now, using the left navigation pane, I can choose Post Graduation and then the Post Graduation form opens up. I have also written the JS which will flip between the two forms (based on the value selected in the new_degreetype) for existing records. It is undoubtedly ugly because it loads the form twice.

**Question**:

1. How do I get this to work with new forms. That is, when the user
   clicks on New, I want to display a pop up where the user is supposed
   to pick Graduation or Post Graduation and depending upon the value
   chosen there, I open the right form in Create mode.
2. How can I prevent the user from choosing the other form via the Left
       Navigation pane. So, when the user tries to change the form from
       Graduation to Post Graduation, display a Message and say "Sorry!
       This is not allowed". Alternatively, can I remove that completely -
       not give the user the option to be able to flip the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the form differs?  It would probably be easier to have a single form, and use javascript to change the way it looks (hidding/showing/enabling/disabling certain fields).  The control over which forms the user sees is based on security roles and how you define the hierarchy.  Trying to get it to do something it wasn't designed to do, may be more pain than it is worth.

Comment: Thanks, but that is an argument that I have already lost. This is my first Dynamics CRM project and the Solution Architect would not agree to having one form with sections that are made visible / hidden based on  Degree type. Also, all users should be able to use both the forms - the only difference is to open the right form based on Degree Type. Irrespective of the pain, is there a supported way to get it accomplished?

Comment: @Kanini - I'm not aware of a supported method of accomplishing it.  Microsoft created a whole JavaScript library to provide a supported way of hidding/showing sections/fields.  I'd personally challenge the Solution Architect, on why not, and query how you're supposed to do it otherwise.

Comment: Where can I find this whole JavaScript library? Is it part of the SDK - because, within the SDK/samplecode/js/formscripts, I find quite a lot of JS files including one formselectorsamples and other ones such as formitemsamples / tabsamples / uisamples etc., Is it one of them?

Comment: @Kanini I'm talking about the built in Library that is a part of CRM itself.  Check out this cheat sheet: http://danielcai.blogspot.com/2011/04/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-javascript.html.